# upgrade from 8.9.2 to 9.1.0

Tags: updating, composer

I have a drupal 8.9.2 installation with many modules.

I ran upgrade_status and applied patches or upgraded modules to dev version like suggested.

```
fhebert@fhebert-communication:/var/www/domain.com$ composer show drupal/core-recommended
```

=> package not found

I have drupal core installed

I then ran a :

fhebert@fhebert-communication:/var/www/domain.com$ vendor/bin/composer require 'drupal/core:9.1.0 as 8.9.2' drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9.0.0 drupal/core-project-message:^9.0.0 --update-with-dependencies --no-update

I've followed the path of aliasing the version like the doc says. But nevertheless i got this error :

```
 Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.2
- Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.2
- Conclusion: remove drupal/big_pipe_sessionless 1.2.0
- Conclusion: don't install drupal/big_pipe_sessionless 1.2.0
- Installation request for symfony/debug ^3.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug[3.4.x-dev, v3.4.0, v3.4.0-BETA1, v3.4.0-BETA2, v3.4.0-BETA3, v3.4.0-BETA4, v3.4.0-RC1, v3.4.0-RC2, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.4, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v3.4.47, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
- Installation request for drupal/big_pipe_sessionless ^1.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/big_pipe_sessionless[1.x-dev, 1.2.0].
- Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 9.1.0
- drupal/big_pipe_sessionless 1.x-dev requires drupal/core ^8.3.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.3.x-dev, 8.4.x-dev, 8.5.x-dev, 8.7.x-dev, 8.8.x-dev, 8.9.x-dev, 8.9.2].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.8.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.9.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.8.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.9.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.4.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.5.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.4.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.5.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[9.1.0, 8.7.x-dev].
- Installation request for drupal/core 9.1.0 as 8.9.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[9.1.0].
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Which docs advice to use composer version aliasing? I'd consider this an extremly dangerous pratice when used with major versions (major versions changes are major because they contain breaking changes!) Why don't you require`big_pipe_sessionles:^2` instead of aliasing core?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! For Composer questions please always add your composer.json to the question. Many thanks 

Comment: I'm with @Hudri - this is at least the 2nd/3rd time I've seen someone using this aliasing technique, and even if you do manage to force it through it's surely going to make it even harder to keep updating in future. Who's advising that as a solution? Where did you see it? As Hudri also mentions, the best course of action is to upgrade the contrib modules to versions that are compatible with Drupal 9. You're going to need to do that anyway, or eventually you'll run into broken code

Comment: you've got the point guys. I will try this. I see the aliasing path here : https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-higher

Comment: Ah ok - those docs say only do that if you need to (you don't need to here, the module has a suitable release), and also to undo it afterwards. The world makes sense again